# Python 3 list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am completely new to Python and I have an error I don't understand. I have a function called mult1 which I want to take a list "a" and multiply each element together and output the total so that a list of [1,2,3,4] would output 24. I am getting an error "list index is out of bounds" at line 4

```
def mult1(a):
   n=1
   for i in a:
      n=n*a[i-1]
   print(n)
```

My function works with the input [1,2,3,4] but not with [7,8,1,2]. Why is this?

Comment: `for i in a` iterates over the elements of the list, not their indices. You need `n = n*i`

Comment: Hint: add `print(i)` into your `for` to see what `i` is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the python for loop relies on the iteration protocol
so when you write

```
for i in a:
  print(a)
```

you are ***actually accessing those indices*** hence there's no need to use the `[i]` (indexing ) notation like you would do in a conventional c/c++/java for-loop.

to answer your question

```
def mult1(a):
  n = 1
  for i in a:
    n *= i
  return n
```

Comment: why was this answer downvoted? please provide suggestions to improve if you downvote

Comment: @7stud yes you are actually accessing those indices, if not then please provide the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

you are actually iterating over the values and not the indices. hence i refers to the value in the list

```
def mult1(a):
   n=1
   for i in a:
      n=n*i
   print(n)
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation on the behaviour for him to lear, not just post the solution code

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that "i" would be the value in "a". I assumed it acted as an index

Comment: @Porteous96: Python is not JavaScript (fortunately).

Comment: thanks @DanielSanchez, i added some explanation. please remove the downvote.

Comment: why the downvote now?

Answer (score -1):

> My function works with the input [1,2,3,4] but not with [7,8,1,2]. Why
>   is this

When you read the first number 7, then 7 is assigned to `i`.  Then you try to lookup the number at `a[i-1]` => `a[7-1]` =>`a[6]`--and 6 is out of bounds.

You don't need to get the index of the numbers in the list to multiply all the numbers together:

```
def mult1(nums):
    total = 1

    for num in nums:
        total *= num

    print(total)

mult1([7,8, 1, 2])

--output:-
112
```

Answer (score -2):

I will start with explaining the behavior you have observed, and finish by showing a much better way of achieving your goal.

When you use `[1, 2, 3, 4]` the `for` loop evaluates to `n=n*a[0]`, `n=n*a[1]`, `n=n*a[2]` and `n=n*a[3]` and that works as you have 4 elements in the list.

However, when your list is `[7, 8, 1, 2]` the first iteration of the `for` loop evaluates to `n=n*a[6]` which throws an `Index out of bounds` exception has it tries to access the 7th element of a 4 element list.

There are many simple ways to multiply all the elements in a list. Two of them:

```
print (functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [7, 8, 1, 2]))
>> 112

####################

li = [7, 8, 1, 2]
mul = 1
for num in li:
    mul *= num
print (mul)
>> 112
```